# Linear Differential Equation Implication

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I don't really understand the conclusion in green. I understand that if you have a linear differential equation you can sum solutions to get others but I don't understand why this implies $a_o$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $y = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ix^i$, we will have $y(0) = a_0$.  No matter what you happen to select for $a_0$, we can still build a suitable rest of the sequence.

Remember though, we don't have to think about this problem in terms of solving for the infinite series.  In the green statement, the author observes that no matter what you choose $a_0$ to be, the system of equations
$$
y' = \sin(x) y; \qquad y(0) = a_0
$$
is an *initial value problem*, which means it will have a *unique* solution.

He then uses linearity to say something else: if we know that $y_1(x)$ is a solution to the system
$$
y' = \sin(x) y; \qquad y(0) = 1
$$
then $a_0 \cdot y_1$ will be a solution to the system
$$
y' = \sin(x) y; \qquad y(0) = a_0
$$

Answer (score 1):

When you solve a linear differential equation using the power series method, you will find that there will be one degree of freedom. That is once you choose $a_0$, the other terms will be determined recursively from $a_0$.

For instance if we assume that $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ solves $$y' = \sin(x) y$$ then we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} \right) \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \right)$$

For the sake of explanation, let's for the moment define $\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$.

This tells us that $$(n+1)a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_{n+1-k} b_k = \sum_{m=0, 2m+1 \le n+1} a_{n+1 - (2m+1)} b_{2m+1}$$

Thus $a_1 = a_0 b_{1} = a_0$, $a_2 = \frac{a_1 b_1}{2} = \frac{a_1}{2}$, $a_3 = \frac{a_0 \frac{-1}{3!} + a_2}{3}$ and so forth. So once $a_0$ is determined, so is $a_1$. This means $a_2$ is determined, and then $a_3$ etc.

Finally by plugging in zero into $y$ we find $y(0) = a_0$, and this is our initial condition.

Incidentally, this differential equation is solvable by means of a separation of variables. $$y'/y = \sin(x)$$ so that $$\ln y = -\cos(x) + C$$ and $$y = e^c \cdot e^{-\cos(x)} = (a_0e) e^{-\cos(x)}$$ So if you would like to check your work, this may be helpful.